# Save form data array to previous array with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array in my script.js, such as:

```
 $scope.companies = [
        {
            id: '1',
            contact: 'John',
            address: 'Some street, United States',
            function: 'Client',
            telephone: '0123455858446',
            fax: '0128289385',
            url: 'http://www.example.com'
        },

    ];
```

Then there is a form to add a new item to the array - once the form is submitted, it creates its own array item, then 'pushes' it to the old array.

The console.log then prints out the completed array and it has all the data.

However, if I then browse to a different page, where it displays the data in a table, it doesn't show it - and it hasn't added the array item to the script.js.

How do I go about this?

**script.js:**

```
    // Define a new module for our app
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'UserApp']);
var appName = 'My App';

// Config the route
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController',
            public: false
        }).
        when('/companies', {
            templateUrl: 'companies.html',
            controller: 'CompaniesController',
            public: false
        }).
        when('/companies/add', {
            templateUrl: 'add-company.html',
            controller: 'CompaniesController',
            public: false
        }).
        when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            login: true
        }).
        when('/management/create-user', {
            templateUrl: 'management/create-user.html',
            public: false
        }).
        when('/account/edit/:userid', {
            templateUrl: 'account/edit.html',
            controller: 'EditAccountController',
            public: false
        }).
        when('/profile/:userid', {
            templateUrl: 'account/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
            public: false
        }).
        otherwise({
            templateUrl: '404.html'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

app.run(function(user) {
    user.init({ appId: 'REMOVED' });
});

app.controller("DashboardController", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Dashboard';
});

app.controller("CompaniesController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Companies';
    $scope.title_sub = 'Add Company';

    $scope.add = function(newCompany) {
        $scope.companyData = [
            {
                id: newCompany.id,
                primary_contact: newCompany.primary_contact,
                address: newCompany.address,
                function: newCompany.function,
                telephone: newCompany.phone,
                fax: newCompany.fax,
                url: newCompany.url
            }
            ];
        console.log(newCompany);
        console.log($scope.companyData);
        console.log($scope.companies);
        $scope.companies.push.apply($scope.companies, $scope.companyData);
    };

    $scope.companies = [
        {
            id: '1',
            contact: 'John',
            address: 'Some street, United States',
            function: 'Client',
            telephone: '0123455858446',
            fax: '0128289385',
            url: 'http://www.example.com'
        },
    ];
}]);

app.controller('GlobalController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.appName = "My App";
    }]);

app.controller("LoginController", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Login';
});

app.controller('EditAccountController', ['$scope' ,'$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.title = 'Edit Account';
    $scope.update = function(userAccount) {
        UserApp.User.save({
            "user_id": $routeParams.userid,
            "first_name": userAccount.first_name,
            "last_name": userAccount.last_name,
            "email": userAccount.email,
            "properties": {
                "phone": userAccount.phone
            }
        }, function (error, result) {
            if (result) {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.saveUser = 'Your account has been updated.';
                })
            } else if (error) {
                $scope.saveUser = "Something went wrong. Please try again!";
            }
            else {
                $scope.saveUser = "Something went wrong. Please try again!";
            }
        });
    }
}]);

app.controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', '$routeParams',  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.title = 'Profile';
    UserApp.User.get({
        "user_id": $routeParams.userid
    }, function(error, result){
        // Handle error/result
        if (result) {
            $scope.$apply(function(

            ) {
                $scope.getUser = result[0]
            })
        } else if (error) {
            $scope.getUser = error
        }
    });
}]);
```

**add-company.html:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>{{ title_sub }}</h1>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p>Add a new company.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>ID</label><input type="text" name="id" id="id" ng-model="newCompany.id" tabindex="1" class="form-control">
                <label>Primary Contact</label><input type="text" name="primary_contact" id="primary_contact" tabindex="2" ng-model="newCompany.primary_contact" class="form-control">
                <label>Address</label><input type="text" name="address" id="address" tabindex="2" ng-model="newCompany.address" class="form-control">
                <label>Function</label><input type="text" name="function" id="function" tabindex="2" ng-model="newCompany.function" class="form-control">
                <label>Telephone</label><input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" tabindex="2" ng-model="newCompany.phone" class="form-control">
                <label>Fax</label><input type="text" name="fax" id="fax" tabindex="2" ng-model="newCompany.fax" class="form-control">
                <label>URL</label></lab><input type="text" name="url" id="url" tabindex="2" ng-model="newCompany.url" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <input type="submit" name="add-submit" id="add-submit" tabindex="10" ng-click="add(newCompany)" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Add Company">
                        <br>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <p ng-show="addCompany"><span class="label label-info">{{ addCompany }}</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit: new controller:**

```
app.controller("CompaniesController", ['$scope', 'companyService', function($scope, companyService) {
    $scope.title = 'Companies';
    $scope.title_sub = 'Add Company';

   $scope.add = function(newCompany) {
       companyService.addCompany( {
           id: newCompany.id,
           primary_contact: newCompany.primary_contact,
           address: newCompany.address,
           function: newCompany.function,
           telephone: newCompany.phone,
           fax: newCompany.fax,
           url: newCompany.url
       });
    };

    $scope.companies = companyService.getCompanies();

}]);
```

Comment: Show the entire code. Does different page have a different associated controller?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing the code...

Comment: The issue sounds like when you navigate to another page, it's not an angular way. If the page refreshes or you click a link that doesn't involve angular routing, your controller is reset and you lose this pushed index. If you want your data to persist in the controller, you need to stick with angular routing methods

Comment: Will post more code in a moment, wasn't sure what to show exactly.

Comment: All the routes are via Angular - including the links, there's nothing external or outside of Angular. The page where the array item is created uses the same controller as where it is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

example using a service, you have to "inject" the service in every controller, as Im doing in  EditAccountController

```
app.service('companyService',[function(){
     var companies = [];
     return {
         addCompany: function(company){
            companies.push(company);
         },
         getCompanies: function(){ 
               return companies;
         }
     }
}]);

app.controller('EditAccountController', ['$scope', 'companyService', function($scope, companyService){

 $scope.companies = companyService.getCompanies();
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be potentially working... now I'm not sure how I actually add data from the form into this service. Once the button is clicked, it should pass the field ID's or names with the values into it and create it as a new array item. So a text field with id 'phone' would be in the format: phone: 0123456789 in the array.

Comment: actually, in the controller that handles the Form you only have to 1. Inject the companyService. 2 call companyService.addCompany(formData). formData is an object with every field of the form.

Comment: `$scope.add = function(newCompany) {
        companyService.addCompany = [
            {
                id: newCompany.id,
                primary_contact: newCompany.primary_contact,
                address: newCompany.address,
                function: newCompany.function,
                telephone: newCompany.phone,
                fax: newCompany.fax,
                url: newCompany.url
            }
            ];
    };`

is the code I have now for adding the form data... but it doesn't seem to do anything / work?

Comment: actually you're not calling the companService.addCompany function. you have to change it to something like:    companyService.addCompany( { id: newCompany.id, primary_contact: newCompany.primary_contact, address: newCompany.address, function: newCompany.function, telephone: newCompany.phone, fax: newCompany.fax, url: newCompany.url });

Comment: $scope.add = function(newCompany) {
       companyService.addCompany( {
           id: newCompany.id,
           primary_contact: newCompany.primary_contact,
           address: newCompany.address,
           function: newCompany.function,
           telephone: newCompany.phone,
           fax: newCompany.fax,
           url: newCompany.url
       });
    };

is the new code. This still doesn't actually add anything. Am I doing something stupid? I'm new to Angular, started yesterday.

Comment: actually that should be working. show me the entire controller please

Comment: if you have the service as the service that I created (without the 'this' variable) should be working. can you create a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Actually it does work... kind of. If i submit the form, then go to the listing page, it shows. However, if i refresh... it disappears. Seems it isn't being saved permanently.

Comment: in that case you will need localStorage or sessionStorage. as I wrote in my first comment ;) use localStorge in the service to add/retrieve data. youre data will persist on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

you mean that you are browsing to another page  after you submit the data and save it into the array?

If you go to another page you will lose the memory that Javascript have in the previous page, in order to save the data you can use sessionStorage or localStorage

one way could be this

```
$scope.origData = [];

$scope.addData = function(data){
 $scope.origData.push(data);
 localStorage.setItem('storedData', $scope.origData);
}
```

Here I'm using the native javascript localStorage object to access the Database, but there is a module to work with the storages in an angular way [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) (read about it)

with the native localStorage object, you will be able to access the data in any page you have in your project with this.

```
$scope.dataOnPreviousPage = localStorage.getItem('storedData')
```

Comment: Not exactly - the form submits and the data should be saved, however if you look at my script.js, it has an array already created with one item. When the form is submitted, I want it to add to that array and keep it stored in the script.js, so that anyone using the 'app' can view the data.

Comment: In that case, I recommend you to use a service to keep the information of the companies and use it throughout  your different pages.

Comment: Would you be able to show how I could get something like that set-up with the code I provided? I've had a look at factory's/services, but I'm not too sure how to do it in this context.

Comment: I just wrote another post with an example

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the array in the $rootScope?

```
 $rootScope.companies = [
        {
            id: '1',
            contact: 'John',
            address: 'Some street, United States',
            function: 'Client',
            telephone: '0123455858446',
            fax: '0128289385',
            url: 'http://www.example.com'
        },

    ];
```

Comment: Same issue, as soon as I browse to the List Companies page, it has been lost. I need it to save it into that array in script.js permanently.